# Is it possible to use Safari on OSX with "panes" like vim splits

Tags: macos, safari

I'd like to have two "tabs" open in one window, but with the content of the two displayed pages simultaneously visible like this:

```
==================
|  content of 1  |
|  content of 1  |
-------------------
|  content of 2  |
|  content of 2  |
===================
```

I don't *want* the toolbar and location bar atop each content area, but I could tolerate this.

The difference between this arrangement and just two Safari windows opened one atop the other is that if I resize the single containing window, the panes resize in lockstep with it.

By the way, it would be even better still if I could have these groups of panes *within* a tab, and tab between such groups (again, like vi(m) tabs/splits).

This doesn't seem remotely possible with basic Safari, but maybe a plugin enables it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of anything, Safari extension or otherwise that would allow you to split a tab in that way (one over the other, both visible, if I understand correctly). Though I am not the end-all oracle of Safari extensions. Searching Safari extensions repositories (apple or others) would be how I would approach this.

Perhaps there is such an extension for Firefox, Chrome or even Opera that I am not aware of?

Comment: There are indeed extensions/add-ons for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/tile%20tab?utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-et-na-us-oc-webstrapp&utm_medium=et&_category=extensions) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=tile+tabs&appver=&platform=), respectively, that accomplish this. I don't believe Safari Extensions have the necessary abilities to perform manipulation like this, though.

Comment: +1; I hadn't thought to search for these as "[tiles](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Does-Safari-has-Tile-tabs-like-Chrome-and-Firefox)." Many of the linked extensions seem just to try to make "tiling windows" easier, whereas what I want would be a "window of tiles." (A few of the extensions do seem to attempt that.) Again, the key point is that it's one window, paned/tiled into sub-windows. (@SteveChambers yes, both visible simultaneously is correct.)